# Extrem Feedback Devices

Tags: discussion

Are Extrem Feedback Devices and Software which are used to create them (Dashboards etc.) considered on-topic?

It feels like it could be because it can and will help Users in the scope of DevOps (System status, build status, code quality, etc.) but im not quite sure if it is.

PS: I ask because i would like to ask a Question regarding how a XFD Dashboard could be realized that get the information mostly from Atlassian Products (Bamboo, Jira, Sonar,...) because the Atlasboard (an old NodeJS Application) is very much out of date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is an answer or just a long comment. And I'm not here for a long time, so take my advice with a huge grain of salt.

As far s I understand it, anything related disseminating know-how and promoting good DevOps and CI practices in the professional field are on-topic here. That being said, even in the site has reached its public beta stage, it is still in its infancy. And the community has probably not yet reached the critical point for strong consensus to emerges about what is on-topic or not.

So, my suggestion would be to simply post your question. If it is well-received. Great. If it is not, don't take it personally: consider it was an experiment.

Finally, remember you can always self-answer your own questions when you'll gain more understanding of the topic or of your issue. The great thing about self-answered questions is not only you share your knowledge, but you also give the opportunity for a more experienced user to correct you, or to post new answers when the technology evolves. As a bonus side effect, that would also improve some of [our stats](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops), since, at the time of this writing, we have 75% answered questions but only 1.7 answers on average per question.